# Django urls for Website not pointing to the correct page

Tags: python, html, django, web

I am using django to help create a website. The problem is when I attempt to switch from page to page the page can't be found and the url reads:

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/mentorPage/

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/mentorPage/mentorPage/

As  I click on the mentorPage link multiple times. I have attached my urls code below and was wondering if anyone could tell me why this is happening.

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from webapp.models import UE
# Create your views here.
app_name = "main"

urlpatterns = [
path('', views.home, name = 'home'),
path('home', views.home, name = 'home'),
path('resourcePage/', views.resource, name = 'resource'),
path('mentorPage/', views.mentorPage, name = 'resource'),
path('aboutMePage/', views.aboutME, name = 'resource'),
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, this happens because you specify a relative path in your link (in page HTML) like this: `href="mentorPage/"`. When it should be an absolute path: `href="/mentorPage/"`